Debug console is not showing anything while running a flutter app in debug mode with external usb connected android phone

When debugging flutter app in vs code, nothing is showing in debug console rather than Connecting to VM Service as shown in image. The app is connected with external usb with my android phone. Earlier it was working fine. Please help me to find out a solution...

I recommend restarting VSCode too. 
Also off and on to Device's developer mode.
If you refer to the debug console a lot,
the flutter_logcat package will help.

I have follwed this steps and just device's developer mode OFF and ON resulted come back of debug logs. Now it's working fine. Thank you...

I'm really glad.
I'm so happy that I could help.
Let's stay close from now on.
Have a great day!
